# figure and figcaption not converting correctly to Word images with captions

Tags: html, ms-word, docx

I have HTML5 source code (with full doctype/head/body) that needs to be converted to a Word DOCX file. The HTML file is generated page with minimal formatting (`H1/H2/P`) and images (`img`).

There is a `FIGURE` that contains the image source (`SRC`) parameter, and then there is a `FIGCAPTION` tag that contains the caption for the image, similar to this (from https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp ):

```
 <figure>
  <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
  <figcaption>Fig1. - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

The image and caption shows properly when the HTML5 page is viewed in a browser.

The issue is importing that HTML5 document into Word 2010 DOCX document (via File, Open, then File, Save As a DOCX). The caption (`figcaption`) is not converted into a DOCX image caption, but is displayed separately (outside) of the image. If you look at the image's attributes (in Word), the caption is not there; the caption is just text that is not 'part of' the image.

How do I get the `figcaption` text to be a caption in an image in the DOCX file?

(I don't have HTML-to-DOCX converters availabe - like Pandoc; I have tried several HTML-to-DOCX JS converters, and they don't solve the problem. Note that this issue is not with displaying the HTML in a browser, but in the conversion of HTML into DOCX when there are figure/figcaption tags.)

**Added**: the intent is to get pictures with their captions into the DOCX with additional text content. Pictures need to be side-by-side, not in separate 'rows'.

Comment: Word doesn't support "linking" a caption with an image or integrating a caption into the image. Captions in Word are pargarphs, just like any other, usually formatted with the **Caption style** and possibly having numbering applied via an SEQ field (that's how Word's user functionality does it). Often, we place images and their captions into a table in order to physically keep them together, especially if non-standard positioning on the page is an issue.

Comment: So there is no way to get a figcaption into the 'insert caption' text in Word after importing the HTML into Word (via File, Open)? Maybe a macro? There are many pictures in the HTML code that have to be 'captionized' - don't really want to do that manually.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean? If you want it to be formatted as a caption you might try changing the html element to <caption>; see if Word will automatically apply the Caption style (analog to Heading 1 for H1). Word doesn't "pick up" text from the document and show it in the "Insert caption" dialog box. If you want to use a macro then you need some way to identify the captions in the document once it's been converted to Word. If it brings across the Fig. # for example you can create a macro that searchs for that pattern, then manipulates the paragraph in whatever manner you require.

Comment: Using a caption tag for the caption does not convert to a Word caption. And I can put the pictures in individual tables (with the picture and caption in separate rows in a one-column table), but then the tables cannot be placed side-by side (as in a picture book with side-by-side pictures, each picture with it's own caption).