# Convert Figure Alt Description to Picture Caption in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need a way to get an image's Alt Description (specified in HTML) into the Word DOCX image's Caption. This needs to be done with many images in a document, so a macro would be best.

Assume an HTML doc with an img tag similar to this

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/path/to/image/picture01.jpg" 
title="picture 01 title" 
alt="this is alt text" 
caption="this is a caption field">
```

This HTML doc is imported into Word 2010 (via File, Open). The image will show in the doc.

Now, how to get the 'title' attribute (which shows up in the Format Picture's Alt-Text dialog as the Description - see screenshot below) into the image's Caption?

Note that the `caption` parameter in the image tag is not converted to a Word Caption for that image.

Sample Alt-Text dialog for an image which shows the image's `alt` value as the Description 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think you've hit on a good way to make the conversion. Glad you were able to find it!

The code below will loop all the *InlineShapes* in the document and, if the Alternative Text is not empty, create a caption using that text.

InsertCaption is only available in VBA for InlineShapes. The user can insert captions for Shapes (graphics with text wrap formatting) because Word evaluates the selected graphic and creates a Textbox of the same width and positions it immediately below the graphic. The Shape and textbox are not, however, linked together in any way. So this functionality is not offered in VBA and would require some "creative" programming.

```
Sub InsertCaptionFromAltText()
    Dim doc as Word.Document
    Dim ils As word.InlineShape
    Dim captionText As String

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set ils = doc.InlineShapes(1)
    For each ils in doc.InlineShapes
      captionText = ils.AlternativeText
      If Len(captionText) > 0 Then
          ils.Range.InsertCaption Label:=wdCaptionFigure, _
                                  Title:=captionText, _
                                  Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow
      End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this (and the other answer) are close to my intent. The 'alt' parameter of the 'src' HTML tag needs to be the caption for the picture, with the caption text under the picture. If there is no alt parameter, then no caption. Right now, both answers seem to put the URL of the picture as the caption, in addition to any caption (alt) text. And I don't want the 'Fig x' text to be there. So, each solution (which seem to work similarly) need to be adjusted to the above requirements.

Comment: I answered exactly what you asked in your Question. It appears you didn't thoroughly research what you need, or didn't specify it exactly. As for the numbering: look at the details of InsertCaption in the Word object model. StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: The issue with this solution is that the Caption is not created; if you click on the picture and select 'insert caption', one would expect the caption to be there. And the solution puts the caption text 'under' the picture, rather than 'associating' the caption with the picture. So if you move the picture, the caption does not move with it. The need is for the picture and caption to be 'together' (so they move together) and visible under the picture.

Comment: My question: to get 'alt' parameter into a Caption. It puts caption below the image, but I expected it to be in the Insert Caption dialog (which appears to make a new one, not let you edit the current one). I also expected to have the caption move with the image if I put the image somewhere else. It appears that my understanding of Caption is incomplete; if you want the caption to be linked (locked?) to the image, you need to perform a separate process to 'group' the caption to the image; which was my goal, although not well stated. I marked yours as correct, but was not my ultimate goal.

Comment: @RickHellewell As I explained in my comment to your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48935359/figure-and-figcaption-not-converting-correctly-to-word-images-with-captions) it's not possible to "link" a caption to a picture in Word - Word just doesn't have the facility to do it. It's also not going to be possible to "group" an InlineShape with a Caption - they will be two separate paragraphs. They could be combined in a one- or two-cell table, then moving the table would move them together...

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Word has a `Range.InsertCaption` method, which will insert field codes to automatically number images. As you were asking to insert Alternative Text, my feeling is you were using the term caption simply as a directive to get the text beneath each image on its own carriage return. So that's what this code does:

```
Sub GenerateAltTextCaptions()

Dim AltTextCaption As String
Dim ImageRange As Range

Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToFirst
With ActiveDocument
    For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
        AltTextCaption = .InlineShapes(i).AlternativeText
        Set ImageRange = .InlineShapes(i).Range
        ImageRange.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        ImageRange.InsertAfter vbCr
        ImageRange.InsertAfter AltTextCaption
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I think this (and the other answer) are close to my intent. The 'alt' parameter of the 'src' HTML tag needs to be the caption for the picture, with the caption text under the picture. If there is no alt parameter, then no caption. Right now, both answers seem to put the URL of the picture as the caption, in addition to any caption (alt) text. And I don't want the 'Fig x' text to be there. So, each solution (which seem to work similarly) need to be adjusted to the above requirements.

Comment: Try this: open your web page in Chrome, press CTRL-S, and when saving choose `Save as type: Webpage, Complete`. This should save your webpage and all its images locally (with local references), which will allow the macro to work (once the webpage is saved as a Word doc).

Comment: joeschwa -- that step is not required; you can do the same thing by opening the HTML in Word, then use the 'Edit Links to File' on the File, Info menu (or on the right - it's easy to miss); in there select all images, check the 'Save Picture in Document', then the 'Break All Links' button. That will make the picture 'local' to the document.

Comment: @RickHellewell that's true. My macro will work with severing the links in Word and with saving the complete website in Chrome as each will make the link references local. So are you saying the macro is now working for you? If it is, will you mark the answer as the correct one by clicking the check mark icon next to it?

Comment: No, the solution does not work as I wish it to. The alt-text needs to be grabbed from the alt parameter of the img tag, and placed in the Caption of the picture. And when you move the picture, the Caption should go with it, always displaying under the picture.

Comment: @RickHellewell you contradict yourself ("I don't want the 'Fig x' text" vs wanting caption text in Insert Caption which requires  'Fig x'). You also ask for additional solutions not stated in the original question. That is not how SO works. If you want more help, you can mark one of the supplied answers as correct (they answer the question that was asked). Then ask another to solve your additional issues. When you demand what you wish for instead of accept help that solved what was asked, [you risk alienating those who would otherwise help you](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258279/752832).